# authentication flows for secured applications

Tags: node.js, authentication

There are many secured applications developed in node.js. However, I could not find any framework (like [Spring-security](https://spring.io/projects/spring-security) in Java) that can be used to save the trouble of managing the authentication (login/logout).

Going further, there are many flows like create-account, forgot-password, change password etc. that each application developer has to develop by himself... What am I missing here? Is there such a framework that I am not familiar with?

**I am not talking about UI form which are obviously application-specific, but I am talking about the logic itself which is mostly common to all apps.**

If not, is it possible to design such a module?

Comment: Have a look at Oauth 2; for example, [here](https://blog.logrocket.com/implementing-oauth-2-0-in-node-js/).

Comment: If you're referring to the actual UI, like a "Create Account" form and a "Forgot Password" form, those are properly part of your application, and therefore your responsibility to build.  The reason this is the case is twofold: 1.  There are many different UI technologies, and 2.  There are many different UI designs.  That's why there's no universal Contact form, Order form, etc.

Comment: I am not talking about UI form which are obviously application-specific, but I am talking about the logic itself which is mostly common to all apps. (see edit)

Comment: Then see the link in my first comment above.

Comment: i still do not understand why the down votes?

Comment: If you hover your mouse cursor over the downvote button, the tooltip that appears describes the guidance for using it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Long ago I have developed [authentication-flows](https://github.com/OhadR/authentication-flows) for Java over Spring, and recently I wrote [authentication-flows-js](https://github.com/OhadR/authentication-flows-js).

It is a module that answers most flows - authentication, registration, forgot-password, change password etc., and it is secured enough so applications can use it without the fear that it will be easily hacked.

It is **for node.js applications** (written in TypeScript) that use express. It is an **open source** (in GitHub). A release version is on [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/authentication-flows-js), so you can use it as a dependency in your `package.json`.

You can find [here an example for a hosting application](https://github.com/OhadR/authentication-flows-js-app).

> NOTE: I have heard comments like "It's not so difficult to implement". True.
> But you have to make sure you take care of all cases. For example,
> what happens if a user tries to create account that is already exists?
> what happens if a user tries to create account that is already exists
> but inactive? what about the policy of the password? (too long/too
> short/how many capital etc.) what about sending the email with the
> activation link to the user? how you create this link? should you
> encrypt it? what about the controller that will receive the click on
> the link and activate the account? and more...

Comment: https://ohad-redlich.medium.com/authentication-create-account-forgot-password-and-change-password-for-node-js-ae1df4df9b43